# SQL Query to get data from before current time

Tags: mysql, sql, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to run a query that will allow me to pick out the rows that have the time before current time.

I want to pick out the rows that are before the current time not after. Am i able to order this in a way that can do can do this.

Currently this is my query.

```
var key = require('../validateApiKey');



// an example of executing a SQL statement directly
 module.exports =   {"get": [key,function (request, response, next) {
    var query = {
        sql: 'SELECT dbo.medicine.medname, \
        dbo.medicine.packsize,\
        dbo.medicine.id as "medicationid",\
        dbo.usermedication.isactive, \
        dbo.usermedication.reminder, \
        dbo.usermedication.communityfeedback, \
        dbo.usermedication.frequency, \
        dbo.usermedication.directions, \
        dbo.usermeddosagetime.usermedid, \
        dbo.usermeddosagetime.time,\
        dbo.usermedication.datetimetotake,  \
        dbo.usermeddosagetime.dosage,\
        dbo.usermeddosagetime.dosageunit\
        FROM dbo.usermedication INNER JOIN dbo.medicine ON dbo.usermedication.medicationid = dbo.medicine.id  
     INNER JOIN dbo.usermeddosagetime ON dbo.usermedication.id = dbo.usermeddosagetime.usermedid 
     WHERE dbo.usermedication.userid = @userid AND dbo.usermedication.isactive = 1',
       parameters: [
            { name: 'userid', value: request.query.userid }
        ]

    };


    request.azureMobile.data.execute(query)
        .then(function (results) {
            response.json(results);
        });
}]
```

};

Comment: How are you storing the time?

Comment: And which time field is the one you want to limit results by? `dbo.usermeddosagetime.time` or `dbo.usermedication.datetimetotake` (or some other field all together)?

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? (Looks more like MS SQL Server.)

Comment: @Jason its type in the database is a string

Comment: @EricBrandt Sorry i want to limit the results by the dbo.usermeddosagetime.time field

Comment: Ouch. A string. I think we'll need to see some sample data, then. I've seen all manner of odd string formats for time, so converting it to something useful for a comparison will depend entirely on the chosen format.

Comment: If at all possible fix that - doing time comparisons based on a string value will be painful at best.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following condition to the `WHERE` clause:

*MySQL*

```
AND dbo.usermeddosagetime.time < NOW()
```

*SQL Server*

```
AND dbo.usermeddosagetime.time < GETDATE()
```

Comment: Tried both of these but no joy, the api will no longer load the data when i add this in.